# Excel crashing on VBA Code - DLP At fault

Tags: excel, vba, crash-reports

I have a pretty weird problem. The code worked fine in Excel 2010 but when our users were upgraded to Office 365 (Excel 2016 Version 1708 Build 8431.2280) this line of code crashes excel:

```
Sheets("Loc_063 BIS").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Copy
```

When I look in the Reliability Monitor I see this:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.8431.2280, time stamp: 0x5b35b959
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.8431.2280, time stamp: 0x5b35b959
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00010d23
Faulting process id: 0x3f1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d438aee914e49e
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Report Id: 34066ee7-a4b0-11e8-b773-0c5415d253c9
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Also DW20.exe crashes and that's the windows error reporting tool. That shows this in the log as to why it's crashing:

```
Faulting application name: DW20.EXE, version: 16.0.8431.2280, time stamp: 0x5b35dd4a
Faulting module name: fcagpph32.dll, version: 11.0.200.100, time stamp: 0x5a54c4ed
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0031155f
Faulting process id: 0x1944
Faulting application start time: 0x01d438bcf62b6e24
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\DW\DW20.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\McAfee\DLP\Agent\fcagpph32.dll
Report Id: cb983d3e-6ef1-4839-8728-ddb85678bf4c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

To me it looks like DLP (Data Loss Prevention) is at fault here. Looking for validation of that, and also in the Excel crash how does one figure out this line:

```
Faulting process id: 0x3f1c
```

What is 0x3f1c? Why wouldn't it just be in decimal?

Comment: This looks like a McAfee problem, not an Excel problem.  See [this KB article](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB71660) to see if it contains anything of use, otherwise I would contact McAfee.

Comment: What's the "reliability monitor"?

Comment: @BruceWayne In windows 10, click start then type reliability, and click View reliability history. It will show you apps that have crashed, if you've had any BSOD's.

Comment: @BillSchanks - Oh, woah - I have never seen that, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I re-created excel doc, and that has resolved my issue. So no more crashing when copying data.